# Sharepoint, changing a class of CSS in Sharepoint Modal Dialog

Tags: development, branding

How can I change a name of class in Sharepoint Modal dialog. I want to color a background of massage so it be good to change a  name of class=**"ms-dlgFrameContainer"**, but where could i Find this class to change it ?
Here is a HTML from firebug. I want to add a 4 modal werb with 4 kind of background-color:

`<div class="ms-dlgBorder" style="width: 400px; height: 107px;">
<input class="ms-hidden" type="button" value="Umieść fokus na końcu okna dialogowego">
<div class="ms-dlgTitle" style="width: 400px;">
<div class="ms-dlgFrameContainer" style="width: 400px; height: 75px;">
<div>Dzień w którym wpisujesz projekt jest dniem świątecznym, czyli ustawowo wolnym od pracy, informujemy Cię o tym.</div>`

Comment: I am glad you got success in opening a Modal Dialog :)

Comment: Yes but after many many many of trying :) ;) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the modals are generated via javascript, and the classes and objects which wrap it are controlled within the JS file. Your best bet is to add a CSS to your master page which overrides ms-dlgFrameContainer with your preferred styling.

HTH

Comment: But i must done it 4 times to have 4 Background-colors. I tryed done it with div, but i don't know how set up a lenght and hight of div. And I tryed to give a div {} Next Color div div {} Next color div div div{} and next color div div div div{} But the height of the column are diferent

Comment: CSS will allow you to do multiple DIVs, something like DIV DIV DIV {css}, however each div you provided has a class name, so you can override each one directly, DIV.className {css}

Comment: Yes but how put in Sharepoint Modal dialog a class

Comment: You can override the out of the box CSS that the modal dialog uses using the method that @DavidLozzi provided, there should be no need to inject custom inline styles or classes into it. That said, you must follow good CSS practices, which means your new class you're overriding with has to follow the same or greater specificity than the classes used by SharePoint, or your styles won't override it. Use Firebug to look at the full CSS selector name for the div(s) you want to change, and use that same selector to define your new look. Load that CSS in your master, and it'll be used in the dialog.

Comment: So I schould put a lot of dives with classes, and call from dives with classes from the last ones to nerest ones. Thanks